# Update the Live app with new Bundle Identifier

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

I have an application live on App Store(version 1.0). Now i have to provide an update to the same application(version 1.1). But, due to some issue i need to change the bundle identifier of the app. Is it possible to do that? If yes please tell me how to do the same. Or i have to create new App ID.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry!! you can't do that because when you are going to upload it as a new version so your current bundle identifier must have to match with previous one. Else create a new app Id and upload it as a new app..

Comment: Thanks 4 ur prompt reply. Actually i'm just making some enhancement to the app. Originally it was developed by another developer and i don't know why he added bundle id as only the AppName and didn't follow the convention(i.e com.xyz.AppName). Now i need to integrate google+ signin for the app. For that to Create an OAuth 2.0 Client ID on google developer portal i need bundle id something like com.xyz.Appname else it gives me invalid_request while google+ sign in. Is there a way to solve this.. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: As far I knew it's not possible. Lets see if other can give any solution.

Comment: Yes, there is no way to change the bundle id from an app.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the bundle identifier. The bundle identifier is the key that is used to identify the app. So when you are going to submit an update the same bundle identifier (used for first submission) should be used.

Another option is to go with a  separate app submission by creating a new app....

Hope this helps